# How can i get the link to download j2ee in java using wget

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, wget

I know this the webpage to download java for linux but where i could get the link which i can put in putty terminal with wget

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SingleVariationTypeFilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_SMI-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/java_ee_sdk-6u1-unix.sh?BundledLineItemUUID=djeJ_hCy.KEAAAEu3.EIRFeX&OrderID=IECJ_hCykN0AAAEuz.EIRFeX&ProductID=uWOJ_hCy5a4AAAEpeiFudDgF&FileName=/java_ee_sdk-6u1-unix.sh

Comment: thats i .sh file , can i get the j2ee.tar.gz file . i could not execute that

Comment: That was an example. You have to go till the stage where the download pop-up opens in your browser. At that stage, cancel the download, copy the link and do `wget`.